# How can I reduce commuting workers?

Tags: simcity-2013

In my city, it looks like $$-jobs are outnumbered by commuting workers from another city. I assume this means my own $$-workers can't get a job.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

[image: Workers]

It doesn't necessarily mean your local workers will be out of jobs, as they usually fill the jobs before commuting outsiders do.

I assume your population detail screen looks similar to my above one. My "Total Jobs" is too high for my available Workers, so "Commuting In" is trying to fill that gap.

Here are your options for fixing:

1) **Raise your $$ workers so you get less Commuting In.**

2) **Reduce $$ jobs**

3) **Communicate with the other city** to tell them to fill their own jobs so their workers don't look to commute to your city.

Answer (score 0):

Make your number of work places match your population.  In a test city I have 71 percent $, 24 percent $$ and 5 percent $$$.  In addition everyone in your city must be able to get work if it is there. Alternatively increase the number of of your $$ residents.  This will reduce the space for your $ residents and they will commute if you can't create room for them.[image: My test city, New Amsterdam]